# Android Native API ANativeWindow_setFrameRate is undefined when linking

Tags: android

Inside my "native.cpp" file I reference the native method;
`ANativeWindow_setFrameRate`

But when I compile I get;

> ld: error: undefined symbol: ANativeWindow_setFrameRate

Inside of "CMakeLists.txt" file I specify -landroid to link with API. Why am I getting this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
# add lib dependencies
target_link_libraries(native-activity
    android
    native_app_glue
    **nativewindow**
    EGL
    GLESv1_CM
    log)
```

You need to add nativewindow libary in you CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: And have you call this function successfully? 
I tried this API but it doesn't take any framerate switching effect.